# Couldn't anyone defeat Voldemort if they destroyed all of his Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

My question is fairly straight forward.

I do recognize the prophecy which states,

"**The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches** ... born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies ... and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not ... and **either must die at the hand of the other** for neither can live while the other survives ... the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies ..."

Is this the only fact to counter-attack my question? Is Harry the only one to vanquish the Dark Lord? And that they must die at the hand of the other? Voldemort would be mortal again when his Horcruxes have been destroyed, so **a mortal man could be killed**, with difficulty of course, as Voldemort is an extremely powerful wizard.

I may be easily overlooking the answer, however, why couldn't anyone kill Voldemort when his horcruxes have been destroyed.

Comment: Because it was a Prophecy!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Theoretically, **someone else can defeat Voldemort as well** (after his last soul piece, inside Harry, is gone. Remember that Harry served as a last pseudo-Horcrux).

   The prophecy wording is "the one with the power to vanquish", not "the ONLY one with the power".
2. Practically, Harry is the most likely person to be able to defeat Voldemort, because Harry is the Master of the Elder Wand at the time it's relevant.

   There probably aren't quite that many wizards who can, aside from Harry, since Dumbledore is dead and everyone else is, to put it bluntly, fully inferior to Voldemort as a wizard and don't have Harry's special edge.
3. As far as "either must die at the hand of the other, for neither can live while the other survives" - that piece mostly refers to the fact that one could only kill Voldemort **after he "killed" Harry and destroyed his own last soul piece within pseudo-Horcrux Harry**, but that he himself serves as pseudo-Horcrux for Harry due to Harry's blood (and Lily's protection) blood he took to make his new body.

   This is covered in "*King's Cross*" conversation that Harry has with Dumbledore, in *DH*:

   > “Precisely!” said Dumbledore. “He took your blood and rebuilt his living body with it! Your blood in his veins, Harry, Lily’s protection inside both of you! He tethered you to life while he lives!”
   >
   > “**I live… while he lives? But I thought… I thought it was the other way around! I thought we both had to die? Or is it the same thing?**”

Comment: Severus could very well be able to carry on Dumbledores plan, in the meantime, when not in his or any other Death Eater's presence. However, I like the solution.

Comment: There were plenty of witches and wizards that eclipsed Harry in skill and power.   Harry had no special edge once Voldemort killed the horcrux within Harry.   The only thing Harry had going for him was that he bothered Voldemort and the elder wand wouldn't harm it's master

Comment: @Robert - Harry's edge that the answer referred to was specifically the ownership of the Elder Wand

Comment: Does everyone forget that Neville was also considered to potentially be the chosen one?

Answer (score 4):

It would be take an **uncommonly skilled witch or wizard**

This quote is directly from **Half-Blood Prince**

> Harry sat in thought for a moment, then asked, “So if all of his Horcruxes are destroyed, Voldemort could be killed?”
>   “Yes, I think so,” said Dumbledore. “Without his Horcruxes, Voldemort will be a mortal man with a maimed and diminished soul. Never forget, though, that while his soul may be damaged be- yond repair, ***his brain and his magical powers remain intact. It will take uncommon skill and power to kill a wizard like Voldemort even without his Horcruxes.”***

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, anyone could kill a Horcruxless Voldemort.

Dumbledore goes to great pains to explain to Harry that the prophecy does not have inherent validity. The validity of the prophecy is that Voldemort accepted it. As such Voldemort would not rest until he killed Harry, which meant that practically one of them would (probably) end up killing the other. The following two excerpts are from Chapter Twenty-Three of *Half-Blood Prince*. You may want to read the whole conversation there for the full context but what follows are, I think, the most important paragraphs:

> "But," sputtered Harry, "but you said the prophecy means —"
>
> "If Voldemort had never heard the prophecy, would it have been fulfilled? Would it have meant anything? Of course not! Do you think every prophecy in the Hall of Prophecy has been fulfilled?

> "Of course you would!" cried Dumbledore. "You see, the prophecy does not mean you *have* to do anything! But the prophecy caused Lord Voldemort to *mark you as his equal*.... In other words, you are free to choose your way, quite free to turn your back on the prophecy! But Voldemort continues to set store by the prophecy. He will continue to hunt you... which makes it certain, really, that —"
>
> "That one of us is going to end up killing the other," said Harry. "Yes."

Compounding the situation is the fact that a piece of Voldemort's soul is lodged inside of Harry. In order for Voldemort to be killed, Harry has to be killed first. Since Harry had to die regardless, Dumbledore decided to have Harry be the one to do everything in the fight against Voldemort so that no one else would have to die needlessly. Harry realizes this at the end of *Deathly Hallows* after seeing Snape's memories:

> Dumbledore’s betrayal was almost nothing. Of course there had been a bigger plan; Harry had simply been too foolish to see it, he realized that now. He had never questioned his own assumption that Dumbledore wanted him alive. Now he saw that his life span had always been determined by how long it took to eliminate all the Horcruxes. Dumbledore had passed the job of destroying them to him, and obediently he had continued to chip away at the bonds tying not only Voldemort, but himself, to life! How neat, how elegant, not to waste any more lives, but to give the dangerous task to the boy who had already been marked for slaughter, and whose death would not be a calamity, but another blow against Voldemort.

So again, Harry being the one to kill Voldemort was not a technicality, but a practicality. If, for whatever reason, Harry would be unsuccessful at killing Voldemort, someone else would have to do it. Harry himself acknowledges this:

> But Dumbledore had overestimated him. He had failed: The snake survived. One Horcrux remained to bind Voldemort to the earth, even after Harry had been killed. True, that would mean an easier job for somebody. He wondered who would do it... Ron and Hermione would know what needed to be done, of course... That would have been why Dumbledore wanted him to confide in two others... so that if he fulfilled his true destiny a little early, they could carry on...

Comment: The question has an answer in one of your quotes. In the book, it is implied that 
technically anyone can kill the last piece of Voldemort's soul- While he is walking to his death, Harry thinks someone else will do it eventually-"True, that would mean an easier job for somebody. He wondered who would do it...". Also, Harry is given the option of actually dying in the chapter at King's cross, so basically the universe would actually have an immortal tyrant if Harry chooses to die. Somehow I cannot accept a flawed and dreadful universe like that.

Comment: @Shanty sorry, I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit add comment :D

Comment: @Shanty So... you're agreeing with my answer but adding an additional argument?

Comment: Yes. I did not want to post another answer as your answer covers my main point. Just added a supporting point to comments.